# Is there a way from one Phone/Tablet module start Activity to another module activity within the same app without creating a new app in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-module

```
  val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
        .setClassName( "com.example.AnotherPhoneTabletModule","com.example.AnotherPhoneTabletModule.MainActivity")
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND)
        .setComponent(ComponentName("com.example.AnotherPhoneTabletModule", "com.example.AnotherPhoneTabletModule.MainActivity"))

    applicationContext.startActivity(intent)[1]
```

There are two phone/tablet modules and want to do start activity in another module. However, from the reason of setting flag or category the other module is creating different application. Is it possible in same application to start another activity from another phone/tablet module without using android library module.

[Two different apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Buh.png)

Comment: You should remove flag addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND) and start by activity context

Comment: It returns "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)"
this error not worked unfortunately @Công Hải

Comment: No dont use application context to start. Did you try start by activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME).setClassName("com.example.AnotherPhoneTabletModule","com.example.AnotherPhoneTabletModule.MainActivity")
            .setComponent(ComponentName("com.example.AnotherPhoneTabletModule", "com.example.AnotherPhoneTabletModule.MainActivity"))

        startActivity(intent)
```

This code worked for me.